# Account creating error in Postgresql 9.0 under Windows Server 2008 vs ArcGIS INSPRE modul

Tags: windows-server-2008, arcgis-server, postgresql-9.0, phppgadmin

Helo,

we have got some problem with Postgresql and ArcGIS INSPIRE modul.

First of all, we are not experted and experienced in this problem, so sorry for the "amateur" sentences.

The problem is that, when we try to create an account in pgAdminIII and we restart, the connection with a database / service is not being established and losing the settings that worked before.

Trying to connect with the admin, we have got similar error message:

http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.8/images/no-hba.png

We are using the inbuilt postgresql.conf editor to change the

listen_addresses = '*' , but it was okay.

we changed the pg_hba.conf too (added the required parameters), but when we finished the editing and saved, the added line is disappeared from the file.

After the restart the postgresql was unable to connect to the database so we had to change back to the original settings / conf-file.

We find that a lot of parameter could be changed in these .conf files, but we do not understand that what is wrong.

Thanks. That's all. :)

Answer (score 0):

:)

So it looks like it works!
And it looks like that we were really far from the solution.

Our solution is:

- with the pgAdminIII we had to create a new user, theb change the pg_hba.conf -add new connection, like one of the well known variant:

  host all all xxx.xx.xx.xx/32 md5
- pg_pass.conf also changed, like

  localhost 5432 *database username password*
- then we had to get a [postgre client](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Setting_up_a_connection_to_PostgreSQL/002p0000003q000000/) for the ArcGIS too
- and finally it works!!!